# How To Call a String From A Different Method Than It Was Originally Declared

Tags: string, methods

I'm trying to write an Oregon Trail type story in java. In one of the methods later on, you are asked to input your name. I've used this to get the name:

```
Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
String name = keys.nextLine();
```

I would like to keep referring to the player as the name they entered in other methods and I'm unsure on how to call it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does the rest of your code look like?

Answer (score 2):

When you declare

```
String name = keys.nextLine();
```

You are creating a string inside the scope of that method. As you probably noticed, it's no longer accessible once the method finishes. Rather than storing the character name in a variable local to that method, you want to save it to a variable in an outside scope.

In Java's object oriented design, the ideal place to put that would be an instance variable for the relevant class. Say you have some master class called "Game". An instance of this class will represent a running game, have methods for interacting with the game, and hold data about the game. You could have an instance variable in Game declared as:

```
String playerName;
```

If that method is within Game, then you would simply have the code:

```
Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
this.playerName = keys.nextLine();
```

Since you're assigning the name to a variable that exists outside the scope of the method, it will remain accessible to you later. The exact approach to this depends on how you structured your classes.

A more general solution, which could work better than the above solution depending on your code structure, would be to have that method return a String, rather than set one. For instance:

```
String getPlayerName() {
    Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
    return keys.nextLine();
}
```

A method like that would return a string holding the name, which would allow you to work with it outside of the method.